# SEToolkit Not Cloning Login Page

Tags: authentication, web-application, phishing, kali-linux

I am trying to clone a login page with SEToolkit in the latest version of Kali Linux. SEToolkit simply isn't working. I have tried running it with normal user privileges and sudo.  I have placed in all the following options

> (1) Social-Engineering Attacks
>
> (2) Website Attack Vectors
>
> (3) Credential Harvester Attack Method
>
> (2) Site Cloner

I placed in all of the necessary information afterward. This is the only message I receive

> [*] You may need to copy /var/www/* into /var/www/html depending on where your directory structure is.
>
> Press {return} if you understand what we're saying here.
>
> [*] The Social-Engineer Toolkit Credential Harvester Attack
>
> [*] Credential Harvester is running on port 80
>
> [*] Information will be displayed to you as it arrives below:

It just hangs after that. I am expecting tons of information to fly across the terminal screen, but nothing happens. I checked the /www/var/ directory as well as the HTML directory and nothing is populating.

This is a very straightforward tool and I have had no problems with it in the past. I do in fact have internet and I can, in fact, access the login page of the site I am attempting to clone. I attempted to clone multiple sites with the same results. I don't know what other criteria is necessary for this process to work as expected. How can I further diagnose this issue? What else can I check?

Answer (score 2):

I had to stop apache2 using `service apache2 stop`. SEToolkit does NOT use Apache. It uses its own HTTP daemon. I had to Google how to turn apache ON in the config file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and found this thread while searching for a solution which I now wanted to share:

In my case, another service was already using port 80 (which SET seems to need). So the solution was to first find out which process was running on that port:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80
```

(The sudo is needed in case it is a root process, without it not all information would be displayed).

Then the process can be killed:

```
kill [PID]
```